# Keyboard layout doesn't appear in Languages & Inputs

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-layout, input-language

So one day, no idea how it happened, my windows 10 PC added "English UK" to the keyboard layouts list. I already had "English US". So now, when I Alt+Shift through the layouts I have both US and UK layouts.
Later, "English INTL" was added too. So now i my keyboard layouts looks like this:
[image: Keyboard layouts]

The problem is, both these added layouts don't appear in the Language settings in the control panel:

[image: Language settings]

How is this possible and how can I remove these layouts?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/957552/how-to-delete-a-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10 (If you'd asked on the appropriate site, it'd have been easier to find.)

Comment: I saw this page before asking here. The problem is, this didn't work for me. As you can see in the second picture, under English(Unites States) you can see the keyboard layout. There is Only US there (I opened it to double check)

I actually solved it by myself. I'll post my answer here soon :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to solve it by myself.

I had to add the English (United Kingdom) keyboard manually in the settings,
then, in the options of this language I added the "English(United Kingdom) - United states - international keyboard" layout.

Then removed this layout, after which i removed the English (United Kingdom) language.

It seems that Windows 10 didn't update the languages in the settings, so to remove them you first need to add them.

I still have no idea how these languages were added in the first place though..